# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given | TypeError at /accounts/login/$

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.2 and python 3. When I log in I am getting:

```
TypeError at /accounts/login/$
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Please Find the code of my login.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' % }

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Please Login:</h2>
    <h3>(Must be SuperUser, please check with the site admin)</h3>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your Username and password didn''t match! Please try again. </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{% form.as_p %}}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-btn-primary" value="Login">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">

    </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Code of Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/$',views.LoginView,name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/$',views.LogoutView,name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}) 
]
```

Comment: You should use `LoginView.as_view()`. The same for the `LogoutView`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but still getting the same error

Comment: where is code for `views.LoginView` ?